# SVG-images in IE are cropped instead being scaled

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

An SVG newbie needs your help.

I've created some SVG files using Inkscape and trying to implement these in my website scaling them over CSS ( `height:12pt;width:auto;` ).

It does work fine in Chrome and Opera but doesn't in IE 9 and IE for WP8.1:
The images are cropped to the indicated height instead being scaled.

Does anyone have the same issues or even a solution?

Thank you in advance!

[Here's a link to the Image](http://www.sprachvertraut.de/fileadmin/sprachvertraut/svg/xing.svg)

Here's the integration code:

```
<div id="social">Social: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.xing.com/profile/Alexander_Radeke" target="_blank" rel="me"title="Besuchen Sie unser XING-Profil">
<img id="xing" class="svg" src="fileadmin/sprachvertraut/svg/xing.svg"alt="Unser XING-Profil">ing</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
#xing {height:1em;width:1em;border:solid 1px #eef;border-radius:0.2em;margin-bottom:-0.1em;}
```

Do you need more infos?

Comment: Could you post a sample image together with the relevant code, please...

Comment: Thank you for your quick respose. Here's one sample: 
[link](http://www.sprachvertraut.de/fileadmin/sprachvertraut/svg/xing.svg)
The integration code:
'<div id="social">Social: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.xing.com/profile/Alexander_Radeke" target="_blank" rel="me"title="Besuchen Sie unser XING-Profil">
<img id="xing" class="svg" src="fileadmin/sprachvertraut/svg/xing.svg"alt="Unser XING-Profil"> ing</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</div>'

Comment: I think you mean SVG and not CSV. CSV is a comma separated value file, like a spreadsheet. SVGs are vector graphics.

Comment: You should update the question with the code and sample images rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: You're right. I'm already dizzy after trying to find a solution myself ...

Comment: Add a viewBox attribute to the svg file's root svg element.

Comment: - Done but no change. 
- <img ... type="image/svg+xml"> did solve it for a similar image but not for this one.

Comment: Exactly what did you add as the link to the image is unchanged.

Comment: viewBox="0 0 479 552" and preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" In IE for WP 8.1 it did help. IE 9 still doesn't accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive SVG in ie not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215006/responsive-svg-in-ie-not-working)